# Jquery dropdown menu not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I tryd to made a Jquery dropdown menu when i slide the menu item it slides perfecly down and when i leave the menu item it slides perfecly up.

The only problem is when i move my mouse down into the submenu it slides up and what i want is that is stays open untill i leave the menu item or the submenu.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <a href="dashboard.php"><li class="dashboard icon-home">Dashboard</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="icon-pages">Paginas</li></a>
    <a class="trigger" href="#"><li class="afbeeldingen icon-image">Afbeeldingen</li></a>
    <div class="adminsubmenu">
        <a href="#">Submenu item</a>
        <a href="#">Submenu item</a>
        <a href="#">Submenu item</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#"><li class="icon-users">Gebruikers</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="icon-settings">Instellingen</li></a>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
div#adminmenu ul li {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:600;
    padding:7px 0 7px 28px;
    background-color:#fff;
    width:175px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #c2c2c2;
    border-right:1px solid #c2c2c2;
}

div.adminsubmenu {
    height:100px;
    width:175px;
    background:url(../images/adminmenu_bg.png) repeat-y top right #e6e6e6;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(".adminsubmenu").hide();

            $("a.trigger").mouseover(function(){
                $(".adminsubmenu").slideDown();
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                $(".adminsubmenu").slideUp();
            });

        });
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ajuz/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to put the `<a>` inside of the `<li>`, not the other way around, in order to make the HTML valid.

That said, just change your JavaScript to do exactly what you want:

```
$("a.trigger").mouseover(function(){
            $(".adminsubmenu").slideDown();
        });
$('.adminsubmenu').mouseleave(function(){
            $(".adminsubmenu").slideUp();
        });
```

---

Better yet, place the submenu inside the trigger element. That way, you'll still be hovering over the trigger as long as your mouse is over the submenu:

```
<li class="afbeeldingen icon-image trigger">
    <a class="" href="#">Afbeeldingen</a>
    <ul class="adminsubmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

new JS:

```
$(".trigger").mouseover(function () {
    $(".adminsubmenu").stop().slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(".adminsubmenu").stop().slideUp();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/B3GB6/

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a ... </a></li>
```

INSTEAD OF

```
<a><li> </li></a>
```

It's actually the other way round

Answer (score 0):

It was doing exactly what you said. When the mouse leaves `a.trigger` the menu slides up. So you just have to change it to `$(".adminsubmenu").mouseleave`
Here is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ajuz/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".adminsubmenu").hide();

    $("a.trigger").mouseover(function(){
        $(".adminsubmenu").slideDown();
    })
    $(".adminsubmenu").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".adminsubmenu").slideUp();
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes that is almost good but it doesn't work if you mouseleave the class trigger.